# как определить список ближайших городов относительно выбранного города python

Tags: html, python, json, парсер, api

Я вытаскиваю список городов из https://yandex.ru/yaca/geo.c2n. Допустим я беру город Орел и хочу найти ближайшие города, можно ли это сделать ,используя яндекс гео (используя другой запрос или может из индекса). Если нет , то каким образом это лучше сделать ?

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://yandex.ru/yaca/geo.c2n')
r.raise_for_status()
lines = r.content.decode(r.apparent_encoding).splitlines()
regions = dict(line.split('\t') for line in lines)
```

получаю:

```
{'0': 'Регионы',
 '1': 'Москва и область',
 '10': 'Орел',
 '100': 'Франкфурт-на-Майне',
 '10002': 'Северная Америка',
 ...,
 '98': 'Кельн',
 '983': 'Турция',
 '99': 'Мюнхен',
 '994': 'Индия',
 '995': 'Таиланд'}
```

Comment: связанный вопрос [How to determine 4 nearest adjacent points in grid database around given latitude and longitude using python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7784216/4279)